# iOS: 24 hour time formatting not honored with Region=Canada, Language=French

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

If Language is French and Region is Canada, the Languge & Region pane in Settings shows 24 hour time formatting in the sample area as expected, as does the rest of iOS and stock apps.

But if I create a simple SwiftUI app, 12 hour AM/PM formatting is still used.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hourCycle: \(Locale.current.hourCycle.rawValue)")
            Text(Date.now.formatted())
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot showing AM/PM in time]

If I set language to English and region to United Kingdom or other 24 hour time region, I get 24 hour formatting as expected:

[image: screenshot showing 24 hour time in time]

If I use DateFormatter I see the same issue. Note that English-Canada uses AM/PM.

Is this developer error (me!) or a bug in iOS? I tried iOS15 (removing Locale.current.hourCycle  as this is iOS16 only) and see the same issue.

Settings:
[image]

Comment: When you run the app, what value do you see for `Locale.current.identifier` and `Locale.preferredLanguages`? Does your app offer a French localization?

Comment: 12/24 Time can be independently set in settings / date time.

Comment: @PtitXav, my point is that everywhere else in iOS it is showing time in 24 hour format. So using the standard format modes should track that. I have found this is the case normally except for this region-language combination. 

But in my case, it was set to 24 hour mode. If I switch to 12 hour I see iOS time and stock apps change as well. But in either mode time is formatted 12 hour AM/PM in Switft. And in NSDateFormatter example I created.

Comment: @ItaiFerber, Locale.preferredLanguages[0] is "fr-CA" but Locale.current.identifier is en_CA. Even after removing English and restarting.

Comment: To be clear, does your app have a localization for French? This is important, because the locale applied while an app is running depends on the localizations the app offers. Even if the device is set to `fr_CA` (as noted in preferred languages), if the app only offers an English localization, then the language will be overridden to `en`. As you see, the locale identifier becomes `en_CA` as the intersection of "preferred languages" and "available localizations", and as you note, English in Canada prefers AM/PM over 24-hour time, which is what you get.

Comment: Ah, no it does not offer any localization. Thanks for the explanation!